# How to individually render only modified items when a list item is modified using Redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, redux

I created the state of the todo list using Redux.
After calling the todo list with useSelector, I created a todo list component, and created a todoitem component as a child component using the map function in the todo list component.
If the state of the todo item (todo.done) is changed using dispatch in a child component, the entire list is being re-rendered. How can I make sure that only the modified item is re-rendered?
I also tried using memo, but the result didn't change.
reducer

```
const todoSlice = createSlice({ 
  name: 'todo',
  initialState: [],
  reducers: {         
  // action.payload = [id, done]         
   setDone (state, action:PayloadAction<[string, boolean]>) {             
    const targetIndex = state.findIndex(todo => todo.id === action.payload[0]);       
    state[targetIndex].done = action.payload[1]; 
   }
  } 
})
```

list template

```
function List() {
 let todoList = useSelector((state :RootState) => state.todo);
 return (
   <>
    { 
      props.todoList.map(todo => 
          <TodoItem key={todo.id} todo={todo} setDone={props.setDone}/>               
       )       
    }     
   </>  
 )} 
export default memo(List);
```

item template

```
function TodoItem(props: {todo: Todo}) {
  <Row justify='space-between'>
    <Checkbox checked={todo.done} onChange={(e) => {dispatch(setDone([todo.id, e.target.checked])}}>
     <span style={todo.done ? {textDecoration: 'line-through'} : {}}>{todo.todo}</span>        </Checkbox>
   </Row>
 }
 export default memo(TodoItem)
```

Comment: Why do you care? Optimizing to reduce renders unnecessarily is a very common beginner's error in React. Rerenders in your example are very cheap, and adding memorization in places introduces a larger surface area for bugs and unnecessary complexity. Until you have a noticeable performance problem, it is a bad idea to do this.